# Reducing reading from excel file in applet

Tags: java, excel, applet, apache-poi

My applet can already read from an excel file stored in the jar, but to read from the excel file, I have to use 5 other jars (dom4j-2.0.0-ALPHA-2, poi-3.9-20121203, poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203, xbean) which total to 10.1 mb excluding the actual applet jar (1.36 mb).
These take a while to download, so I was wondering if there was a better excel reading library that I could use that was smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Excel file is stored in the JAR, it is not being modified after deployment. This means that you can do all kinds of pre-processing and data extraction (to a more accessible format) as part of your build process (and remove the Excel libraries from your distribution).

Comment: although I up-voted and agree with you, he can want to change to file according to the user and open it on client machine. In that case opting for server-side processing would be the way.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento The file is never changed by the user

Comment: How would I do pre-processing and data extraction without the excel libraries?

Comment: You do use the libraries to do the pre-processing, but this happens when you build your JAR file (on your computer). The applet will no longer need to include POI, just the XML/JSON/CSV/text file that your pre-processing created (you put those in the JAR). At runtime, your applet does not touch the Excel file anymore, just those generated files.